# Username field validation on registration form

Tags: email, forum, validation, username

I have absolutely zero experience with Expression Engine but I've been given a task to fix a validation on a registration form. There's a username field that is supposed to validate as email address only but right now it accepts any string. I have no idea if that registration is a plugin or built in. I found it's template in /themes/forum_themes/site/forum_member

I suspect I need to find a model for the registration db table now and change the validation type from string to email? Or something like that? I have basically no idea where to start without getting to know EE from scratch.

Any help apprieciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the native EE forum template.

I suggest using the jQuery Validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/. You can add the code to the forum header template. I don't know the header template name offhand but it should be in the same directory.

```
<form id="registration" action="">
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    $("#registration").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But it already has a server-side validation applied. I don't want to change it to something new. From experience with other CMSs and frameworks I know it should be possible to just change validation type for this field to 'email'. Can this be done at all?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to use client-side validation for this but I'll let others respond. Someone else may know a way to do it without hacking core code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. Yeah, looks like it may be the best way to go. Certainly faster as it wouldn't require me learning EE :)

Comment: registration_form.html doesn't actually have form declaration line. I can't find a layout that would wrap the registration_form.html. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for the form css ID? Look at the page source on the front-end. There has to be a form tag.